# VBA Excel loop for copy multiple separate cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make a loop, which will copy data from 2 cells at once to the newly created workbook.

So far my code looks as follows:

```
 Dim ObjWorkbook As Workbook, PerWorkbook As Workbook
 Set ObjWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _
 "A:\Master PAYE Costs Dec 23.xlsx")

 Set PerWorkbook = Workbooks.Open( _
   "A:\Name Surname-Feb24-Timesheet 1.xlsx")

 Dim cRng As Range, sRng As Range, c As Range
 Dim Row As Range, totalRng As Range, cell As Range
 Dim strName As String, pName As String

 strName = "-Feb24-Timesheet"

 Dim folderPath As String

 folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path


 Set cRng = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23").Range("AA3:AA103")
 Set sRng = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23").Range("D3:D103")
 Set totalRng = Union(cRng, sRng)


 For Each Row In totalRng.Rows
   For Each cell In Row.Cells
     Debug.Print cell.Value & strName
     PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("B2") = cell.Value
     PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("AM4") = cell.Value
     PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cell.Value & strName & ".xlsx")
   Next cell
 Next Row
```

The code works, but picks up 2 the same cells instead.

How could I make a loop for copying 2 separate cells at once to the new workbook?

UPDATE:

With the code like this:

```
 For Each Row In totalRng.Rows
   For Each cell In Row.Cells
     Debug.Print cell.Value & strName
     PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("B2") = cell.Value
   Next cell
   For Each cell2 In Row.Cells
     PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("AM4") = cell2.Value
   Next cell2
   'ObjWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (
   PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cell.Value & 
 strName & ".xlsx")
   Next cell
 Next Row
```

I am getting an error:

**Invalid cell control variable reference**

for the  `Next cell` penultimate line

Comment: Does `Master PAYE Costs Dec 23.xlsx` get opened?

Comment: I've noticed, that once isn't opened the error occurs. However, this error isn't the pivot thing here as the other part of the code leads to copying 2 separate cells in one go. Updated my question as the error doesn't occur anymore.

Comment: You have 2 `Next cell` in your Update code. Also, you're maybe better off using a normal for-loop so you can use the Ranges with the iteration easier, i.e. `PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("B2").Offset(i-3) = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23").Range("AA" & i).Value` (could use a couple worksheet variables or range variables for both so both can just use `.Offset`). Another thing, your update code shows the desire to save after each cell, should it be after each cell or each row?

Comment: @Notus_Panda save must be after each row. One row includes the cell 1 and cell 2 needed. Once these 2 cells are copied to the newly created workbook, the workbook is saved under the name concatenated from cell 1.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my bad, you want the values to be in the same position, so no offset needed. You can just use an iteration and a couple of arrays for the values to be iterated over.

Instead of setting the ranges/union, use the following:

```
Dim cArr, sArr
cArr = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23").Range("AA3:AA103").Value
sArr = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23").Range("D3:D103").Value

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(cArr, 1)
    PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("B2") = cArr(i, 1)
    PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet").Range("AM4") = sArr(i, 1)
    PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs (folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cArr(i,1) & strName & ".xlsx")
Next i
```

That should take care of it, let me know if something is still off.

Answer (score 1):

### Same Rows of Non-Adjacent Columns

- Notus_Panda's solution is the most efficient and I think you're about ready to implement arrays in your code on your own.
- For the sake of completeness, here's what you could have done.

**`For Each...Next`: Hard Coded**

```vb
Set cRng = ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23").Range("AA3:AA103")
' No 'sRng'!

Dim cell As Range

With PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet")
    For Each cell In cRng.Cells
        .Range("B2").Value = cell.Value
        .Range("AM4").Value = cell.EntireRow.Columns("D").Value
        ' or:
        '.Range("AM4").Value = cell.Offset(, 3).Value
        
        PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cell.Value & strName & ".xlsx"
    Next cell
End With
```

**`For Each...Next`: Implementing a Row Counter**

```vb
With ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23")
    Set cRng = .Range("AA3:AA103")
    Set sRng = .Range("D3:D103")
End With

Dim cell As Range, r As Long

With PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet")
    For Each cell In cRng.Cells
        r = r + 1
        .Range("B2").Value = cell.Value
        .Range("AM4").Value = sRng.Cells(r).Value
        
        PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cell.Value & strName & ".xlsx"
    Next cell
End With
```

**`For...Next`: Assumes a Row Counter**

```vb
With ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23")
    Set cRng = .Range("AA3:AA103")
    Set sRng = .Range("D3:D103")
End With

Dim r As Long
' No 'cell'!

With PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet")
    For r = 1 To cRng.Cells.Count ' or 'cRng.Rows.Count'
        .Range("B2").Value = cRng.Cells(r).Value
        .Range("AM4").Value = sRng.Cells(r).Value
        
        PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cell.Value & strName & ".xlsx"
    Next r
End With
```

**`For Each...Next`: Implementing a Row Counter Using the Range Union**

- Bad!!! This is just for fun. It's almost the same as the 2nd example but longer and more complicated. As you can see, there is no benefit from using the range union with non-adjacent columns.

```vb
With ObjWorkbook.Sheets("Payroll - Nov 23")
    Set cRng = .Range("AA3:AA103")
    Set sRng = .Range("D3:D103")
End With

Set totalRng = Union(cRng, sRng)

Dim cell As Range, r As Long

With PerWorkbook.Sheets("Timesheet")
    For Each cell In totalRng.Areas(1).Cells
        r = r + 1
        .Range("B2").Value = cell.Value
        .Range("AM4").Value = totalRng.Areas(2).Cells(r).Value
        
        PerWorkbook.SaveCopyAs folderPath & "\Timesht\" & cell.Value & strName & ".xlsx"
    Next cell
End With
```